# Converting mp3 to LINEAR_16 or FLAC format for google cloud speech

Tags: java, scala, google-cloud-platform, codec, google-cloud-speech

I have mp3 files I'd like to run through Google's Cloud Speech API [[reference]](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/best-practices) - but just the first 15 seconds of each audio file. I'm working in Scala with jlayer, mp3spi, and tritonus libraries imported as suggested by [JavaZoom](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/documents.html). My code so far looks like this:

```
val in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new URL("mySong.mp3"))
  val baseFormat = in.getFormat
  val decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
    16000,
    16,
    baseFormat.getChannels,
    baseFormat.getChannels * 2,
    16000,
    false)

  val audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in)
  val buffer = new Array[Byte](16000*4*15)
  var i = 0
  while (audioInputStream.available() > 0) {
    i += audioInputStream.read(buffer)
  }

  audioInputStream.close()
  in.close()

 // pass this to API request:
    lazy val recognitionConfig: RecognitionConfig = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder
      .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
      .setLanguageCode("en-US")
      .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
      .build

    val request = RecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
      .setAudio(RecognitionAudio.newBuilder().setContent(ByteString.copyFrom(buffer)).build())
      .setConfig(recognitionConfig)
      .build()
```

However, when I print out the value of the ByteString-copied buffer it's only 0's and the API call returns nothing. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? this is my first time manipulating audio in Java/Scala so I may be missing something obvious...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. You get nothing if the audio is not intelligible or is encoded in a format but not decoded appropriately, and other specifics e.g. th audio file can't be stereo, it needs to be mono.
So I first converted the audio from .mp3 to .flac as follows using the ffmpeg module (in python - you need to find its scala version):

```
# turn the video into audio
ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(inputs={input_file_path: None}, outputs={output_file_path: '-y -vn -acodec flac -ar 16000 -ac 1'})
ff.run()
```

the `input_file_path` and the `out_file_path` are *strings* that contain paths for the input and output audio file locations. Note: you can test the output audio file to see if the conversion was successful using the `play` command.

Having done the above, you can now use `AudioFormat.Encoding.FLAC` and `AudioEncoding.FLAC` instead.